# Using GeoLocation variables in CFSET

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to capture geolocation data and insert it into a database.

The code below is my attempt to capture the browser's longitude and latitude and save the values in two form fields. The problem is the output code generates multiple instances of the two form fields (i.e. "longitude" and "longitude").  Here's a screen shot of a single set of those fields being populated. How do I populate the rest?

[image: Screenshot of generated Form]

**Form Code:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-1" style="color:##000000">
      <tr>
         <td>Tree No</td>
         <td>Current Status</td>
         <td>Graft Successful</td>
         <td>NOT Grafted</td>
         <td>Graft unsuccessful</td>
         <td>Tree Died</td>
      </tr>
      <cfoutput query="rsTreeList" >
         <tr>
            <td>#TreeID#</td>
            <td>#Status#</td>
            <td>
               <form name="form1" method="post" action="Recon_Update_Logic1.cfm?ID=#TreeID#">
                  <img src="images/Icons/Success.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt=""/>
                  <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" />
                  <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Graft Successful">
               </form>
            </td>
            <td>
               <form name="form1" method="post" action="Recon_Update_Logic2.cfm?ID=#TreeID#">
                  <img src="images/Icons/NotGrafted.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt=""/>
                  <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" />
                  <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="NOT Grafted">
               </form>
            </td>
            <td>
               <form name="form1" method="post" action="Recon_Update_Logic3.cfm?ID=#TreeID#">
                  <img src="images/Icons/GraftUnsuccessful.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt=""/>
                  <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Graft Unsuccessful">
               </form>
            </td>
            <td>
               <form name="form1" method="post" action="Recon_Update_Logic4.cfm?ID=#TreeID#">
                  <img src="images/Icons/TreeDead.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt=""/>
                  <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="hidden" />
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Tree Dead">
               </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </cfoutput>
   </table>
</div>
```

The following code attempts to populate all of the "latitude" and "longitude" elements:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#rsTreeList.recordCount#">   
    <script>

    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude; 
        document.getElementByID("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    getLocation();
   </script>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: How do you set the variable with <cfset Latitude = getLocation()>

Comment: You cannot call a JavaScript (client side) function from ColdFusion (server side) code. You can make AJAX calls from JavaScript back to your ColdFusion server. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Capture the Latitude and longitude when a record is inserted into a table. I use cfquery to insert the record into SQL database but do not have an idea how to use the variables generated from the javaScript.

Comment: I used forms to capture the javascript variables but when I post the form the remaining forms data is not populated.

Comment: That's because you cannot capture the variables in ColdFusion from JavaScript (unless you pass it back to your CF server). Instead capture the variables when you are executing the cfquery.

Comment: How do you capture the variables when executing the cfquery?

Comment: The same way you are accessing the variables to store them in the database.

Comment: I am not able to access the geolocation variables from the javascript to use in the cfquery. How does other coldfusion applications capture geolocation data and insert into a database?

Comment: You have to pass any data you need to ColdFusion. If it is client-side data then this can be done via a FORM post or an AJAX post request. Those are the most common ways. [Maybe this will help explain](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1618-ask-ben-converting-javascript-variables-into-coldfusion-variables.htm)

Comment: If you search for "how to pass javascript variable to coldfusion" you will see lots of examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JavaScript variables in ColdFusion tags in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965937/unable-to-access-javascript-variables-in-coldfusion-tags-in-script)

Comment: @Johan - You're misunderstanding how javascript and CF operate. The issue isn't with geolocation values only - it's with *any* client side value. Take a look at the links Miguel-F posted, in particular the diagrams [here](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor) to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: *"I used forms to capture the javascript variables*". Submitting a form via post or get does work. So if you're having problems with that, please post a small test case that reproduces the issue. See [MCVE] for details.

Comment: @Johan - I edited the question to try and clarify what you're asking. Feel free to edit it further.  Also, any html/xml code posted won't be visible to anyone unless you format it with the code button on the toolbar i.e. `{}` or indent it 4 spaces :-)